# SQL Order by clause affected when assigned value during operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-order-by, variable-declaration

I'm using SQL Server and have a `Users` table with these columns:

```
Sr. (int), civil_id (varchar), fname etc
```

What I'm trying to achieve is an ordered insertion of `civil_id` in my user table say 100,101,etc

For this purpose I'm trying to fetch `civil_id` (`varchar` type) of the last row using top 1 and order by and increment it by 1 for my next user insertion.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[check123]                               
AS 
     SET NOCOUNT ON 
     BEGIN

     DECLARE @civic int='';
    
     SELECT TOP 1 @civic = CONVERT(INT, civil_id) 
     FROM Users  
     ORDER BY Sr DESC;

     // just an example here  
     UPDATE Users
     SET civil_id = @civic + 1 
     WHERE Sr = 299
     //old civil_id was 10000 but after update it is 11  
END
```

but the problem is when I order while assigning value to

```
@civic = CONVERT(INT, civil_id) FROM Users
```

I don't get my desired `civil_id`, in fact it doesn't order at all but rather gives 0 or some other output.

My `civil_id` column was `varchar` not `int` so I converted but I think it is still considering ASCII values

Any suggestions?

Note: I can't change column type of `civil_id` to `int` because too many stored procedures already made considering it as `varchar` type.

[image: sample data Sr=int,civil_id=varchar]

Comment: order on INT and VARCHAR column will not return the same result. Please add some sample data so that we can help.

Comment: added please have a look

Comment: Can you please tell us bit more about what is "sr=299"?

Comment: sr is actually primary key of int type which is incremented automatically on an entry into db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over all your query seems correct to me although there are some confusions raised. Lets just suggest some improvement you can perform-

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[check123]                               
AS 
 SET NOCOUNT ON 
 BEGIN

 -- DECLARE @civic int='';
 -- Do not need to assign a blank string which is VARCHAR by default to a 
 -- Integer type variable. You can simply Declare the variable as below-
 DECLARE @civic INT

 SELECT TOP 1 @civic = CONVERT(INT, civil_id) + 1
 -- Directly generate the desired value by adding +1 as shown above
 -- Now your  declared variable @civic contains the final value you wants.
 FROM Users  
 ORDER BY Sr DESC;

 // just an example here  
 UPDATE Users
 SET civil_id = @civic
 WHERE Sr = 299
 //old civil_id was 10000 but after update it is 11  
 -- Not sure what you are checking here by sr = 299
END
```

For the above Query (basically your query), I getting always expected results and you can check it here by changing values with different input [DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2a5b60df31749342ff4a20790673427f)

Now, as the value in @civic is generated as expected, question raise which row you are basically updating by checking "sr= 299" and after that which row you are selecting to check the values updated accordingly or not. If you are updating correct row/s, value should be correct as well as there are no issue with @civic value generation.